# Storing vector XNA Animations

Tags: c#, animation, xna

I'm working on XNA C# when I came upon this problem where I need to store easily editable animation data such that my game will be able to render and play it.

It's something like this:

> I have a texture flying across the screen from (0,0) to (800,600) pixels. This will last 5s.

How do I represent it in data and also write it such that the game is able to interpret and do the necessary in the `Draw` and `Update` methods. It's OK if I need to do some extensive coding.

Comment: If you store the animations as XML then you can load them in via the content pipeline

Comment: you can't really define much of the different animation and transitions in the XML can you?

Comment: @Martin: Any scripted animations would have to come through the content pipeline whether or not they're done in XML, if the project is to work on platforms other than regular PC. Using XML for the structure of an animation DSL provides no benefits over a plain-text one.

Comment: You can use XML for the DSL, but it would feel unwieldy at best. In either case, defining the various activities taken by an animation would have to be done in code; the only thing worthwhile to script would be which activities to use and at what times.

Comment: The reason I mentioned XML is because the content pipeline automatically serealises and deserealises it for you. You define the class in C#, and the pipeline handles writing a serealiser - saves you writing and debugging an entire DSL parser!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple domain specific language could help; create an AnimationDirector class that would interpret the statements from the animation script and do the appropriate work during `Draw` and `Update`. The DSL itself could be as simple as

```
texture 0,0; 800,600; 5.0
```

which will create an object with texture `texture` at (0,0) and move it to (800,600) over a 5 second period, and then destroy it.

If you want something a little more useful,

```
create x texture 0,0
over 5.0 move x 800,600
destroy x
```

which will let you get more creative, and expand the possibilities of animation (such as adding rotation, etc. if you desire such).

Now, when you need to run an animation, just pass the appropriate resource name to the director, and let it handle things from there. Alternatively, you could create some kind of AnimatedEntity which refers to a particular script, and calls the AnimationDirector itself for `Draw` and `Update`; depending on how you've done your engine so far, this might be more fitting to its design.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a quick hint...

The position of the texture can be defined by a mathematical formula, which would give you (0,0) at the start time, and (800,600) five seconds later...

Comment: i know how to define it in a mathematical formula. however, the data stored should be easily editable (i.e. easily readable by human without thinking much) and also there are several animations running together