# How can i use path animation in 2D XNA games?

Tags: c#, animation, xna, 2d

I want my 2D sprites move just along some given paths(provided both position and rotation data) which can be read from separated files, and these files should better can be edited by some external editors or can be easily manually modified. Is there any way to do this in XNA games?

I have read this[Storing vector XNA Animations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2212401/storing-vector-xna-animations)

It says to do this i have to implement a domain specific language for vector animation first, but is there any existing tool/library to save some time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks like a [good reference](http://www.enchantedage.com/node/78). From what I can tell, you can create paths with multiple segments and the sprite will follow the next part of the segment once it reaches the end of the current segment. It shouldn't be hard to add in rotation.

Comment: Don't forget to mark this as the answer if it solves your problem. Otherwise let me know and I'll see what I can do.